# What do you call this element which is usually used to indicate a new feature?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new to Ionic 4.
Can someone please tell me what is the name of this element and how to implement it?
Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a ion-badge. You can find more information about how to implement it on [ionicframework.com](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/badge).

```html
<ion-badge color="danger">Beta</ion-badge>
```